# ¿ Cómo hacer para instanciar objetos al entrar en una colisión 'OnCollisionEnter'?. La idea es instanciar un sistema de partículas

Tags: unity3d

Tengo un script con el siguiente código:

```
public GameObject efectoParticulas;

 void OnCollisionEnter(){

     Instantiate (efectoParticulas, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

 }
```

Y asigno el efecto de partículas correspondiente a esa variable a mi objeto y al haber colisión con otro objeto no se me ejecuta el sistema de partículas. Según un tutorial que he seguido es así pero no me sale. Está en desuso esa instrucción?

Comment: tienes habilitado el elemento como rigidbody?

Comment: pon un `Debug.Log("Entré a la colision");` dentro de `void OnCollisionEnter()` para saber si la colisión se efectúa. Si lo hace, tu problema es con el objeto de particulas

Comment: Sí, entrar en el if que tengo programado entra porque ejecuta otras instrucciones. El problema es entonces mi objeto sí, a ver si consigo localizarlo.

Comment: @fredyfx el otro dia lo hice y no toqué nada de eso... tiene que tener activado eso el objeto? Eso no lo tienen todos?

Comment: Le he puesto rigidbody a los dos objetos, tipo ``colision detection`` = discrete pero... nada, esta asi bien?

Answer (score 1):

El codigo que muestra parece esta bien, otra cosa es que la configuracion del objeto sea la adecuada.

Para que una colision funcione de manera basica tiene que tener lo siguiente:

---

El objeto que tiene el **script** de la colision osea el que la quiere detectar, tiene que tener un **RigidBody**:

`RigidBody`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*lo puede añadir en el boton: <kbd>Add compontent</kbd> -> <kbd>Physics</kbd> -> <kbd>RigidBody</kbd>, la configuracion inicial deberia ser como en la imagen, si no es asi dejela como en la imagen, la `Collision Detection` que comenta en los comentarios no es relevante para este caso, las colisiones son diferentes pero en ambas deberian de instanciarle el objeto*

---

Y tambien tener un `XXX Collider` en el caso de una caja seria por defecto un `Box Collider`, que se le podria asignar otro tipo pero no es base de esta pregunta.

`Box Collider`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*similar a lo mencionado anteriormente si no le aparece lo puede añadir en el boton: <kbd>Add compontent</kbd> -> <kbd>Physics</kbd> -> <kbd>Box Collider</kbd>, la configuracion inicial deberia ser como en la imagen, si no es asi dejela como en la imagen*

---

Ahora tendria que tener un objeto mas o menos de esta manera (el objeto que tiene el script)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Ahora para que el objeto anterior pueda activar las colisiones por llamarlo de alguna manera, el resto de objetos con los que "colisione" tiene que tener un `Box Collider` o similar activado, si se quiere dependiendo de lo que este haciendo pueden tener tambien `RigidBody` pero no es necesario.

---

Ahora Cree una scena nueva olvidese de la que tiene osea en la que esta trabajando y haga este test, es para descartar que tenga opciones cambiadas en la escena en la que esta y no recuerde y esten afectando al comportamiento basico, o cualquier otra cosa:

Cree una nueva scena, cree un cubo que sera el suelo, este asegurese de que tiene un `Collider`, ahora cree otro cubo, con `RigidBody` y `Collider`, situe el cubo con `RigidBody` algunas unidades por encima del suelo, cree un sistema de particular simples el mismo que le sale al crearlo desde el editor sin ninguna modificacion ni nada servira.

---

Ahora este Script:

```
public GameObject efecto_particulas;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other){

    if(efecto_particulas != null){

        Debug.Log("dentro de colision");
        Instantiate (efecto_particulas, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

    }else{

        Debug.Log("el gameobject efecto_particulas es null");

    }

}
```

---

Pongalo en el objeto que tiene el **RigidBody**, ahora desde el editor **añada** el **sistema de particulas** a la variable del script.

---

Si todo va como se espera deberia de instanciarse sin problemas, puede mover la **caja** con el `RigidBody` desde el editor en la pestaña **Scene**, colocandolo en el aire para que al soltarlo toque el **suelo**, esto generaria nuevas instancias.

---

**Nota:** Si lo anterior le funciona pero, despues al adaptarlo a su escena, no le funciona, me gustaria ver el codigo ese que menciona sobre los `if`. Por otra parte si puede usar -> `OnCollisionEnter()` sin parametros, yo se lo deje asi por la costumbre de usar el objeto con el cual colisiona para filtrar el comportamiento.